# Laravel 5.4 translation string doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, localization, translation, laravel-5.4

I'm new to laravel and I tried to use the translation string to do the localization work.

I have done the setlocale work and tested by using `App::getLocale()` which returned 'zh-cn'. (I have added a middleware which set the locale to it and added it to the kernel.php)

And I created the `resources/lang/zh-cn.json` and simply added `{'a':'b'}`

then I post an request from frontend to an controller which should return like

```
return response()->json([
    'status' => __('a')
]);
```

however I still get an response as {'status':'a'}. I don't know where the problem is, or if I misunderstood the way translation string works?

Comment: In JSON single quotes are not standard. Try changing your single quotes to double quotes, like this: `{"a": "b"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON it is standard to use double quotes. If you change the single quotes to double quotes it will return the correct value of `{"status": "b"}`.

So your `zh-cn.json` file should look like this:

```
{
    "a": "b"
}
```